# Как получить значение из строки между символами?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, строки

В строке есть символы `^^` и `^`, а между ними значение. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как его получить? Строка может иметь любую длину, и иметь любое содержание. Символы `^` могут повторяться.

Comment: Дополните вопрос, а то вон в ответах уже уточняющие вопросы пошли вместо самих ответов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rx = new Regex(@"\^{2}([^\^]+)\^"); //один из вариантов
        var text = "sdafasdf^^value1^adgdafg^^value2^sdfdf";
        var matches = rx.Matches(text);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            var m = match.Groups[1].Value; //Берем содержимое скобок (1-ой группы)
            Console.WriteLine(m); 
            //Output:
            //value1
            //value2
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Там всегда такого типа:  текст^^value^текст. То есть в строке не может быть второй раз ^^.

Comment: А, тогда легко. Сейчас изменю ответ.

Comment: Готово. Пробуйте.

Comment: Где вам можно плюсик поставить?)

Comment: Да прям ответ плюсаните)